# change imageview in adapter dynamically from an activity

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview, android-custom-view, custom-adapter

I have a custom list adapter which contains n number of `ImageView` in it. I want to change the image source of particular item in the list from an activity by calling a trigger (without using any onclick).I am getting the position of the item that i need to change, but I don't know how to get the `ImageView` in that particular position. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
public AppCustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, AppCustomClass[] data) {

        super(context, resource, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = resource;
        this.data = data;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                    .getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.showText);
            holder.iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.showImage);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        AppChatClass cfile = data[pos];

        holder.textView.append(cfile.txt);
            if(cfile.img_res < 10)
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lessten);
            else if(cfile.img_res > 10)
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.greaterten);

        return null;
     }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tv;
        public ImageView iv;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your adapter's code?

Comment: Put your code too.. and then what you exactly need. An image will be appreciated.

Comment: When you want to change t imageview u need to change t datastructure acordingly and call notify datasetchange on adapter... DONE

Comment: Have added the adapter code. What i need is, when i get a notification in broadcast receiver, the image must be changed. The receiver is in an activity. If the receiver gets a number 3, then the imageview in the 3rd item in list must change automatically.The img_res will be having a number that is in the textView

Comment: @Merlevede Thanks for the code you posted bro.. i

Comment: @Merlevede Thanks for the code you posted bro... I don't know who deleted it. But that code with slight modification helped me out to solve the issue. Once again thanks a lot for your help.